# How to fix import sibling packages/modules in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this file structure

```
.
└── sample
    ├── one
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   └── util.py
    └── two
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test.py
```

Here is the content of util.py

```py
def isOk():
    return True
```

Here is the content of test.py

```py
from sample.one import util
```

Whenever I'm inside the [two] folder and I type

```sh
python test.py
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from sample.one import util
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sample'
```

How is that possible when I create all folders and `__init__.py` by the book?

It seems that a method to invoke it might be

```sh
python -m two.test
```

Comment: go one folder up and try `python two/test.py`

Comment: @TinNguyen It does not work like that either.

Answer (score 1):

If `one` and `two` are both subpackages of `sample`, then you should add a `sample/__init__.py` which may be empty.

If you then invoke `python -m sample.two.test` from the right directory, it should work.

You could even add package-relative imports like this:

```
# test.py
from ..one import util
```

Comment: The parent directory of `sample` should always work. If `sample` is inside a directory listed in your [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH), you can run it from anywhere!

Comment: So it seems that either run it as module (with -m) and get the benefit of a proper package structure or use it as a simple script  - case in which you need to start making use of sys.path.append(...). Am I right?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. Another way to do the latter would be to have a shellscript with `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/the/right/directory python path/to/script.py`

Answer (score 0):

Please add the dir path to your PYTHONPATH

```
export PYTHONPATH=/PATH/TO/DIR/WHICH/CONTAINS/SAMPLE
```

2 real nice links to go through are:

1. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html
2. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: That is a little painful as it makes the run action to depend on OS (What if I have Windows?) or environment.

Comment: IMO it does not matter whether it is painful or not. The right way would be setting environment variables while configuring your system. You can use sys.path for that. https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path

Comment: sys.path.append(YOUR_PATH_HERE)